# Computing the distance from a point to an intersection of two hyperplanes

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Consider the hyperplanes $\{x | P_1^T \cdot x + q_1 = 0\}$ and $\{x | P_2^T\cdot x + q_2 = 0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and we want to compute te distance from $C$ to the intersection of these hyperplanes.

### Solution

Let $x = C + a \cdot \frac{P_1}{\|P_1\|} + b\cdot \frac{P_2}{\|P_2\|}$ then from
$$
\begin{cases}
P_1^T \cdot \left( C + a \cdot \frac{P_1}{\|P_1\|} + b\cdot \frac{P_2}{\|P_2\|}\right) + q_1 = 0\\
P_2^T \cdot \left( C + a \cdot \frac{P_1}{\|P_1\|} + b\cdot \frac{P_2}{\|P_2\|}\right) + q_2 = 0
\end{cases}
$$  one gets
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \|P_1\| &\frac{P_1^T\cdot P_2}{\|P_1\|}\\ \frac{P_2^T\cdot P_1}{\|P_2\|} &\|P_2\|\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -q1 - P_1^T\cdot C\\ -q_2 - P_2^T\cdot C\end{bmatrix}  
$$ therefore
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a\\ b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \|P_1\| &\frac{P_1^T\cdot P_2}{\|P_1\|}\\ \frac{P_2^T\cdot P_1}{\|P_2\|} &\|P_2\|\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -q1 - P_1^T\cdot C\\ -q_2 - P_2^T\cdot C\end{bmatrix}
$$
Finally one gets the distance as $\|x - C\|^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2\cdot a\cdot b\cdot  \frac{P_1^T\cdot P_2}{\|P_1\|\cdot \|P_2\|}$

### Question

Is the derivation correct? I have seen in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048054/signed-distance-from-point-to-the-intersection-of-two-hyperplanes/2048069#2048069) a solution with Lagranje multipliers, but although somehow similar at some point, not exactly as what I am doing here

Comment: I haven't checked your calculations in detail, but with $a$ and $b$ as in your final display the distance formula looks reasonable. <> If it helps, it suffices to assume $P_1$ and $P_2$ are unit vectors (which simplifies the notation), and (translating everything by $-C$) that we're seeking the distance from _the origin_ to the intersection of two affine hyperplanes. That amounts to finding the point on the intersection that is a linear combination of the normal vectors.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewD.Hwang for your comment!

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang of course it looks ok in $a,b$ ... that is trivial. The real question is if the values of $a,b$ are obtained correctly :) Or at least using the correct technique. It seems to me that this technique can be generalized to finding the distance to an intersection of $k$ hyperplanes ...

Comment: To rephrase/clarify: At first I was tentatively skeptical because your final formula involves quantities $a$ and $b$ that appear without definition the first line of the solution. Then I saw the last displayed formula where you express $a$ and $b$ in terms of geometric data, which looks reasonable (though I haven't checked).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang ahh ... ok! Thank you for your additional explanation!